# R h2o - confusion matrix on cross-validation for mcc threshold

Tags: r, h2o, confusion-matrix

After training my XGBoost model, using 5 fold cross-validation, I would like to get an idea of the model performance on new data. As far as I understand, the performance of the model on each cross-validation run in an acceptable measure of this performance.

Using h2o.performance(best_XGBoost, xval = T) I can get the confusion matrix of the cross-validation. However, the threshold was selected based on F1 and I would like to see the performance using absolute_mcc to select the threshold.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Performance on new data:

```
     h2o.confusionMatrix(object = yourXGBmodelHere, 
                        newdata = yourTestSetHere, 
                        metrics = "absolute_mcc")
```

#### 2. CV performance assessment:

```
fold_ass <- h2o.cross_validation_fold_assignment(model)
cvTrain <- h2o.cbind(data.train, fold_ass)
```

Example: how model 1 performs on the first fold:

```
h2o.confusionMatrix(object=h2o.cross_validation_models(model)[[1]], 
                    newdata=cvTrain[fold_ass == 0, ], 
                    metrics = "absolute_mcc")
```

NB - it assumes that the model was trained with: 
`keep_cross_validation_fold_assignment = TRUE`
and 
`keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE`. So that you can use:

```
h2o.cross_validation_fold_assignment(model)
h2o.cross_validation_predictions(model)

h2o.cross_validation_models(model)
```

Comment: The problem is how to get the cross-validation data, and the model for each fold.

Comment: OK, I thought you had 2 problems

Comment: Your solution solved the issue as I put it, hence I mark it as solved. However, I think there is a subtle difference to what I was really aiming (which I only realised now). H2O performed a combined holdout predictions. With your solution I can end up computing it, by combining the predictions of all folds, but do you know of an integrated way to do it?